# Pilates mat vs reformer ? which is better?

Tags: pilates

I have a sway in my back. I am new to Pilates and it seems to correct the backache and sway in the back tremendously.

But Pilates mat(at home) makes me feel stronger and posture corrects afterwards. Pilates reformer hurts my back. 
I get a lot of recommendations for Reformer, as a beginner.

How come same Pilates technique does not work on Reformer ? Am I doing something wrong while on Reformer? Are there any common mistakes to avoid while working with reformer ?

Any advice for me ?

Comment: Stick with the mat since you don't experience any sort of pain. Do note that the reformer is just a **recommendation** and by no means, you need to buy it. Also, went to google a reformer, and looks more like a torture device

Comment: It is a very interesting quation.
But I don't quite understand you. Do you have a Reformer at home? It's very expensive pleasure, as I know.
Pilates matwork is helped you and your's spine. Why do you are engage in the Reformer and experiance discomfort?
You can deal with increasing load on the floor and complexity of exercises used pilates-gum, fitball, izotonic ring or gumstick. You have very beautiful chance to do and imagine some different exercises, you can focus on a specific part of your body.
If you want to use only Reformer,will go to do it in fitness club, not at home, OK? Because our